# ECMAScript 6 alternatives to collapse and responsible Bootstrap menus?

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to create some responsible hamburger menus in Bootstrap 4 without jQuery, relying only on ECMAScript 6 and it's features. I wasn't able to find alternatives to Bootstrap's collapse.js and animation.js, so i decided to tackle this myself.

What is the preferred way of manipulating the DOM and animating the changes in ES6?

Comment: ES6 has nothing to do with the DOM, it is just a specification for a new version of javascript

Comment: Afaik the DOM API hasn't changed much, but maybe look at http://www.ericponto.com/blog/2014/10/05/es6-dom-library/ for inspiration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no different way really of handling dom manipulation. ES15 brings a lot of structure differences in terms of tools you can use that will make your coding task easier. But a toggle and switching class in the DOM can be done efficiently using ES5

```
const burger = document.querySelector('.burger-menu');
burger.addEventListener('click', handleBurger);

function handleBurger(e) {
    e.currentTarget.classList.toggle('open');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. That's all that Bootstrap's collapse.js is doing?

Comment: I refrain from using libraries for simple things like this. But I think bootstrap might be using jquery. Which underneath should be doing the same thing, yes. But I can not vouch for that 100%

Comment: Thank you! You should do some articles on this. :)

Comment: Would you use querySelectorAll to replicate Bootstrap's data-* functionality?

Comment: BTW, i'm getting a target.classList is undefined.

Comment: It's one menu item. No need to use multiple DOM reads. If you want to create this as a pattern it's best to stick to using classes, data- can get polluted really quickly and it should tailor to a data content. but you cannot toggle it or read from it as easily like a class. Which has classList (contains, toggle, add, remove). Which makes it more flexible and clean to work with. But I can see a good argument for having something like data-animation="slide". Although I would never use it in production it would be a nice experiment. I would try to stick to classes as much as possible.

Comment: Can you post a link to your fiddle, or bin?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116628/discussion-between-oz-lodriguez-and-vinnylinux).